# nmap show me differert result on the same machine

Tags: osx, nmap

when i use nmap without sudo it show me the ports are open as

```
nmap 192.168.1.5

Host is up (0.00091s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
110/tcp open  pop3
143/tcp open  imap
993/tcp open  imaps
995/tcp open  pop3s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.52 seconds
```

but when i use sudo before the command it show me

```
sudo nmap 192.168.1.5

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.00025s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.5 are filtered
MAC Address: 08:00:27:02:14:55 (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 29.23 seconds
```

so my question why the result changed and why i can't get the mac without sudo

my host is macos

Comment: Try running `tcpdump` while you're doing the two `nmap` commands to see if there's a difference in the kind of packets they're sending.

Answer (score 0):

`nmap` *should* show you the MAC address if the target host is on the same network as your machine, but will require root privileges to do the same on a target that is more remote (I'm not getting it to work locally, but I'm not sure my network fulfil the requirements, or if that's [old information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212187/is-it-possible-to-get-the-mac-address-for-machine-using-nmap)).

In general, `nmap` requires root access to use raw TCP packets, which is why running it under `sudo` will generate different results compared to when not running it under `sudo`.

Comment: i know that some command need root access to use raw tcp packets , and to get more information like -O os detection but with me  root access show that the ports are filtered which is confusing

Comment: @user3374544 Yeah, that part _is_ a bit weird. It is also something that I haven't been able to reproduce myself.